# I made an inverter in LTSPICE and it is not working

Tags: ltspice

I made a symbol and library file, and I think I well matched the subckt with the symbol.

I can run the circuit with the inverter but it shows 0V at output node..

Can anybody help me with this problem?

---

```
.SUBCKT inverter_min input output
M2 output input VSS VSS NMOS
M1 output input VDD VDD PMOS
V1 VDD 0 0.5
V2 VSS 0 -0.5
.model PMOS PMOS 
.model NMOS NMOS 
.ENDS inverter_min

------------------

Version 4
SymbolType BLOCK
LINE Normal 16 0 -16 -16
LINE Normal -16 16 16 0
LINE Normal -16 -16 -16 16
LINE Normal -32 0 -16 0
LINE Normal 24 0 32 0
CIRCLE Normal 24 4 16 -4
SYMATTR Description inverter
SYMATTR ModelFile inverter_min.sub
SYMATTR Prefix X
SYMATTR SpiceModel Inverter_min
PIN -32 0 NONE 8
PINATTR PinName A
PINATTR SpiceOrder 1
PIN 32 0 NONE 8
PINATTR PinName B
PINATTR SpiceOrder 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is your subcircuit, as you have built it (omitting the supplies):

[image: really?]

Are you sure this is what you want? I suggest building the schematic in the GUI mode, then using `View > SPICE Netlist` from the menu to copy the netlist.

Comment: I think I set the supplies..
V1 and V2 as you see in the netlist code.
And I don't know what is wrong but I almost copied from "View > SPICE Netlist" in the GUI mode

Comment: @Gyum What are you setting the input to achieve a 0V output?  I built your circuit and setting -0.5V at the input gets +0.5V at the output.  Setting +0.5V at the input gets -0.5V at the output.  This looks like the expected behavior to me.

Comment: @Gyum As Ste points out above, [testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0dFU.png) shows an expected behaviour, though you will need to set some parameters, otherwise you'll be relying on defaults (see them in the help under `LTspice > Circuit Elements > M. MOSFET`). In other words, I showed you the netlist, where if you flip up-side down `M2`, you get what you see in this picture, but simply having those elements in there might not be enough. That's something you have to know what you need and what for.